# Magento 2 Unable to checkout

Tags: magento2

Whenever I try to checkout I am getting infinite loader. When I try to debug I found there is a Javascript error in the console. As you can see in the screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When I debug the javascript file `lib/web/jquery/jquery.validate.js` then I found it is not an issue of a payment method rather it belongs to the shipping address. And in my case the issue start when I start to use Amasty Onestep checkout extension. I hope it will help you.